# Python tkinter prevent colour box from being called before its supposed to

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a button that calls a function that asks the user to select a colour. The problem is the colour selection window gets called immediately and the button doesn't work after you input something into the window.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor

main = tk.Tk()

def color_picker(type):
  color = askcolor(title = 'choose ' + type + ' color')
  return color

track_color = tk.Button(main, text='chose track color', command = color_picker('track'))
track_color.pack()

try :
  main()
except TypeError:
  pass
```

I have no idea why this happens as the function, in theory, is only called when the button is pressed.

Comment: Change `command=color_picker("track")` to `command=lambda: color_picker("track")`

Comment: Also why are you returning from the callback? You know that the result will be thrown out

Comment: @TheLizzard im planning on using it later on to colour the line on a matplotlib graph

Comment: The do that in the function. Everything that you return isn't going to be used.

Comment: @TheLizzard ok i'll set it up to draw the graph in the function. and is there a way i cant limit the amout of colour windows created as ive found that if you spam the button you can create lots of windows

Comment: Since the color chosen cannot be accessed elsewhere, so what the point of calling it by clicking the button?

Comment: @acw1668 ngl i dont really know what im doing i'm planning to have a graph that you can change the colour of and im just trying things out this is basically the only solution of could think of im going to tweak the code to have it accessible from else where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have parenthesis on your function, it gets called before the color is chosen. To prevent this, use lambda.

So replace line 10 with `track_color = tk.Button(main, text='chose track color', command = lambda: color_picker('track'))`.

Your new code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor

main = tk.Tk()


def color_picker(type):
  color = askcolor(title = 'choose ' + type + ' color')


track_color = tk.Button(main, text='chose track color', command = lambda: color_picker('track'))
track_color.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: no point of that `return` statement

Comment: yeah i know i removed it. (I just copied the op's code)

Comment: @TkinterLover isn't this exactly what I said in the comments bellow the question?

Comment: Yeah it looks like it. When I was typing my answer you posted your comment.